# extjs 4.1 tree refresh a specific node

Tags: extjs, tree, store, extjs4.1

I would like to refresh a node of a tree.

I try something like that to refresh the root and it worked:

```
this.getStore('MyTreeStore').load({ params: { id: this.getId().getValue()} });
```

But now I would like to refresh only one Node and not the whole tree.

Comment: What do you mean by refresh? If the store gets loaded ( and you only load 1 value ), it should get autoupdated to the node?

Comment: I mean refresh from the server, if other users make changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best response I found is: `this.getStore('MyTreeStore').load({ node: someNode});`

Comment: No, this reloads all children of the node.

Comment: Of course it loads all children of the node. That's the point. If you only want to reload a lower level child, use THAT one as "someNode".

Comment: How to know the load is success? is there a callback function?

Answer (score -1):

`this.getStore('t').getAt(0).load(this.getId().getValue())`  Will load data only for the record passed to `load` ( http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-static-method-load )

Comment: When I do Ext.getStore('MyStore').getAt(0).load(this.getId().getValue()) I get this error: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getAt'